# Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined in json

Tags: javascript, xml, json, html, xmlhttprequest

I use this code to get my json file online and convert this to website text (translation file).

```
browser = {
    i18n: {
        getMessage: function(e, t) {
            var n;
            if (typeof browser.i18n.strings === "undefined") {
                var r = [navigator.language.replace("-", "_")];
                if (navigator.language.length > 2) {
                    r.push(navigator.language.substring(0, 2))
                }
                if (navigator.language !== "en") {
                    r.push("en")
                }
                browser.i18n.strings = {};
                var i = function(e) {
                    var t = new XMLHttpRequest;
                    t.open("GET", "https://www.website.com/locales/" + e + "/translation.json", true);
                    t.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.responseText) {
                            var e = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                            var t;
                            for (t in e) {
                                if (!browser.i18n.strings[t]) {
                                    var n = e[t].message;
                                    var r = e[t].placeholders;
                                    if (r) {
                                        var i;
                                        for (i in r) {
                                            var s = new RegExp("\\$" + i + "\\$");
                                            n = n.replace(s, r[i].content)
                                        }
                                    }
                                    browser.i18n.strings[t] = n
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    try {
                        t.send()
                    } catch (n) {}
                };
                for (n = 0; n < r.length; n++) {
                    i(r[n])
                }
            }
            if (typeof t === "string") {
                t = [t]
            } else if (!t) {
                t = []
            }
            var s = browser.i18n.strings[e].replace(/\$\$/g, "@@@@");
            for (n = 0; n < t.length; n++) {
                var o = new RegExp("(?!\\$\\$)\\$" + (n + 1), "g");
                s = s.replace(o, t[n])
            }
            return s.replace(/\@\@\@\@/g, "$$")
        }
    }
};
var items = document.querySelectorAll("[data-i18n]");
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var translation = browser.i18n.getMessage(items[i].getAttribute("data-i18n"));
    try {
        if (items[i].value === "i18n") {
            items[i].value = translation
        } else {
            items[i].innerHTML = translation
        }
    } catch (e) {}
}
```

Before this works fine in Google Chrome and Opera. Now it doesn't work.
And it show me always this error:

> Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Any idea how to fix this?

UPDATE:
Here the (translation) json file:

```
  {
  "uparrow":{
    "message":"Up"
  },
  "downarrow":{
    "message":"Down"
  },
  "nextbutton":{
    "message":"Next"
  },
  "slide1welcome":{
    "message":"Welcome User"
  }
}
```

Read this to this HTML code ...TEXT HERE... 
Thanks,

Comment: Add a debugger statement before the replace and inspect the value of `n` at each stage. at some point it becomes undefined. Prevent that to stop the error from occurring.

Comment: Is this a minified version of the code? Any chance you can post the original?

Comment: this is the full Javascript code, in my HTML page I got example this <span data-i18n="nextbutton">next button</span>

Comment: Which line are you getting this error on?

Comment: on this code part "var s = browser.i18n.strings[e].replace(/\$\$/g, "@@@@");"

Answer (score 2):

Seems that there's no such message inside `"https://www.website.com/locales/" + e + "/translation.json"` where `e` - is a language.
So as far as I understand if no `browser.i18n.strings` is defined - then you load messages' translations from `"https://www.website.com/locales/" + e + "/translation.json"` and put it to `browser.i18n.strings`.
Next time when you want to translate a message - you expect that this message is already inside `browser.i18n.strings`. But seems that there's no such key inside `browser.i18n.strings`. That's why get an error. As a hot fix - I would recommend simply to add some code like:

```
...
} else if (!t) {
    t = []
}

var s = "";
if (browser.i18n.strings[e]) {
    s = browser.i18n.strings[e];
} else {
    s = e;
}
s = s.replace(/\$\$/g, "@@@@");

for (n = 0; n < t.length; n++) {
...
```

In that case your message still won't be translated. But there're will be no error though.
For better support you may add some special symbols to detect such **non-translated** message and add an appropriate translations operatively. E.g. surround non-translated messages with square brackets:

```
...
var s = "";
if (browser.i18n.strings[e]) {
    s = browser.i18n.strings[e];
} else {
    s = "[[" + e + "]]";
}
```

**Note:** The code to find translations is `synchronous` but translation loading is `asynchronous`. So when you request the translations first - requests are made but your code continues to be executed. When the response comes - you code has already finished to loop DOM nodes.
As a workaround - you may try to load translations in a synchronous way (simply change the last parameter in `t.open(...)` to `false`) **BUT IT'S NOT A GOOD SOLUTION**: while the translation request is in progress - your page will be unavailable. It's not good from the UX point of view.
So I would recommend to review your architecture and load translations during the initial page load.

Comment: Now it shows only the text inside "nextbutton" (from the HTML code  data-i18n="nextbutton". And no translation of my fr/translation.json

Comment: @user1731468, could you please provide your `fr/translation.json` file? Are you sure that there is such key in it?

Comment: See UPDATE of the json file.

Comment: @user1731468, it works for me with such translation file. Could you prepare a short [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your non-working example

Comment: Here the link https://jsfiddle.net/0utk8ep1/3/   Normal I must see "en haut", "vers le bas". Only shows the text "uparrow "

Comment: @user1731468, see my note in the answer

Comment: the XHR must be open to "true" because Google, Mozilla and Opera:  Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70639/discussion-between-kiril-and-user1731468).